Why don't timers work properly in the background in Flutter?
Originally the timer worked fine in the background, but for some reason it doesn't work now. But another strange thing is that whether in release mode or debug mode, it works properly when I connect the device to the PC and check the log. But when I don't check the log, the timer runs slowly.
Ah, it's an Android environment.
I use the foreground service task and have the app set up to run properly in the background. Below is the code for the problem.
_backUPtimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 6), (Timer timer) {
        totalRecordedTime += 359;
        saveSleepBackupData();
      });

